Same server and same HTML but different results: embedded YouTube blocking
I run a webserver divided into two sections: a marketing area, managed by Joomla, and a technical area which is mostly static HTML.
The Joomla expert reported that embedding YouTube videos wasn't working and asked for assistance.  I hit "View source" on a Joomla page exhibiting the problem and copied everything into a file in the static area of the site.  Th original page shows "Blocked Page.  An error occurred during a connection to www.youtube.com." while the copied page worked without problems.
On examination, Joomla is using an iframe with a src attribute pointing to the YouTube video so the actual call to YouTube is made by the browser, not the server.
I have used Firefox's "web developer tools" to compare the request headers of the GET requests passed to YouTube and they are identical.  Both receive a 200 response, even though one has a 96 kB payload and the other nothing.  The response headers differ in time-stamps and some indecipherable cookie content but are otherwise identical.
I have no explanation for this and don't know how to begin to fix it.
Bad page: https://www.guralp.com/component/sppagebuilder/page/157
Good page: https://www.guralp.com/howtos/vid_test/copy.html
(Note that the HTML returned by these will be slightly different until the browser "accepts cookies" on the bad/Joomla page.)
I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.
Yours,
<°}}}>«<

It's to do with your headers.
The site it is not working on has Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy set to require-corp.
See this question, though note that solutions such as the credentialless attribute has limited support.

Thank-you very much: that's let me solve the problem. I had to change our COEP to "unsafe-none" because YouTube have not set the correct header to allow embedding in a COOP/COEP environment, despite it being on their issue-tracker for over two years!
